# How do I make an iterator over a 2-dimensional table in Lua?

Tags: loops, multidimensional-array, lua, iterator

I've got a lua table made of tables, so it's two-dimensional: root -> child -> grandchild.

None of the levels of this hierarchy is guaranteed to be "array-like". The first level has integers with "nil gaps", and second one is not even indexed by integers (but by tables).

The table in question is a private structure inside a lib. I want to provide a way for the library user to parse its grandchildren. I don't care much about the order in which the they are parsed, as long as all of them are.

The first thing I thought about was using a function accepting a callback:

```
-- this scope has access to root 
function eachGrandChild(callback)
  for _,child in pairs(root) do
    for index,grandChild in pairs(child)
      callback(index, grandChild)
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
-- no access to root, only to eachGrandChild
eachGrandChild(function(index, grandChild) print(index, grandChild) end)
```

This much is understood.

**My question is: could I provide a similar functionality using an [iterator](http://www.lua.org/pil/7.1.html) instead?**

I'm talking about something that would allow me to do this:

```
for index,grandChild in iterator() do
  print(index, grandChild)
end
```

I've been thinking about this for a while but I'm not able to crack it. All the examples I've seen use numbers to easily "manage the state of the iterator" on each iteration. Since I don't have numbers, I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Coroutines](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.6) make it easy to write this kind of iterator. A coroutine is a function whose execution can be suspended and resumed, conceptually like a thread. A coroutine can contain deeply nested loops, yield a value from the inner most loop, then continue right where it left off when resumed. When it yields, the caller who resumed it can receive yielded values.

In your case, convert `eachGrandChild` into a generator function which *yields* grandchildren.

```
function eachGrandChild(root)
  for _,child in pairs(root) do
    for index,grandChild in pairs(child) do
      coroutine.yield(index, grandChild)
    end
  end
end
```

Then use `coroutine.wrap` to create a function that will create a coroutine for your generator and resume it each time the function is called.

```
function grandChildren(t)
    return coroutine.wrap(function() eachGrandChild(t) end)
end
```

Now you have your iterator:

```
for key, val in grandChildren(root) do
    print(key, val)
end
```

[There's a chapter on this in Programming in Lua.](http://www.lua.org/pil/9.3.html)

Comment: Awesome answer. The "managing the state of a function" part I said was practically yelling "coroutines!" to me, but I didn't connect the dots. I'm a bit concerned about execution speed (this parsing loop will be executed many times per frame so it has to be reasonably fast) but I'll do some tests.

Comment: @kikito: Your direct callback method is definitely going to be more efficient, in part because of the reduced function call overhead (resume, yield). But it's not as bad as you might think (Lua's coroutines are [very well written](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300682/how-do-i-make-an-iterator-over-a-2-dimensional-table-in-lua)).  For instance, if you benchmark the coroutine implementation vs prapin's implementation, I suspect you'll find the coroutine to be faster.

Comment: you were right in everything. Even when creating a new anonymous function each time, the callback code is the fastest one. Coroutines take around 200% time to do the same job, and the next-based solution takes around 220%. So I guess I'll stick to callbacks. This has been a good learning experience nonetheless! :)

Comment: Just keep in mind, [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Yes, 200% may sound awful, but we're talking about a differences a few *microseconds*. Are you calling this thousands of times per frame?

Comment: "Premature evil is the root of all optimizations" :D I know the quote. And yes, this is going to be called thousands of times per frame - It'll be at the heart of a collision library (`root` is actually a spacial index)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Mud that coroutines are the best approach to the problem.

For the record, I have written an iterator without coroutines for the sake of comparison.

The first function `eachGrandChild` is called for each element. It uses a `state` variable, the containing the two indices (the top and second level).

```
function eachGrandChild(state)
  while state.childIndex ~= nil do
    local child           = root[state.childIndex]
    state.grandChildIndex = next(child, state.grandChildIndex)
    if state.grandChildIndex == nil then
      state.childIndex = next(root, state.childIndex)
    else
      return state.grandChildIndex, child[state.grandChildIndex]                                                                                                                  
    end 
  end 
end
```

The iterator is initialized with the helper function:

```
function grandChildren(root)
  return eachGrandChild, {childIndex = next(root)}
end
```

Now the iterator can be used normally:

```
for key, val in grandChildren(root) do
    print(key, val)
end
```

Compared to the coroutine based version, `eachGrandChild` has more lines of code and is more difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try both approaches nevertheless - yours might be more efficient, if slightly longer. I would declare both answers as correct if possible. You definitively deserve a +1

Comment: I've taken the liberty of refactorizing the iterator code a bit - names instead of magic numbers, a while instead of a repeat-until, and a simplified "run out of grandchildren" condition. I also removed `root` from the state, since it's assumed to be available on the scope. I hope you don't mind if I edit your answer.

Comment: @kikito Thanks for the code editing. This is more readable now.